# How to confiugure maven-enforcer-plugin to exclude some rule in test scope?

Tags: maven, testing, scope, maven-enforcer-plugin

How to confiugure maven-enforcer-plugin to exclude some rule in **test** scope?

I have such a configuration:

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>enforce-bytecode-version</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>enforce</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <rules>
        <enforceBytecodeVersion>
          <maxJdkVersion>1.7</maxJdkVersion>
        </enforceBytecodeVersion>
      </rules>
      <fail>true</fail>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

But I would like to check JDK version only for regular code and not for test scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can simply being done by using the [appropriate configuration](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/enforceBytecodeVersion.html):

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-bytecode-version</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <enforceBytecodeVersion>
                  <maxJdkVersion>1.7</maxJdkVersion>
                  <ignoredScopes>
                     <ignoreScope>test</ignoreScope>
                   </ignoredScopes>
                </enforceBytecodeVersion>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

I also would recommend to use a more recent version of [maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/).

Comment: Any idea how to resolve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850449/how-to-resolve-maven-enforcedbytecodeversion-failure @khmarbaise

Comment: Note that `ignoredScopes` does not seem to be allowed in `bannedDependencies`. For dependencies, you have to include the scope in the artifact description (`groupId[:artifactId][:version][:type][:scope][:classifier]`). Other rules probably have similar ad-hoc stuff instead of allowing `ignoredScopes`. See: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html