# Restricted to JDK 8 yet com.github.snowdrop:java-buildpack-client:jar:main-9ea258e874-1:compile contains dev/ContainerUtils$1.class targeted to JDK 11

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies, java-11

I am developing a Jenkins Pipeline (DSL) plugin. I'm having compatibility issues with maven.

When I run the "mvn install" command I get the following output.

````
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (display-info) @ buildpacks ---
[INFO] Adding ignore: module-info
[WARNING] Invalid bytecodeVersion for com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.12.1:compile : META-INF/versions/11/module-info.class: expected 55, but was 53
[INFO] Restricted to JDK 8 yet com.github.snowdrop:java-buildpack-client:jar:main-9ea258e874-1:compile contains dev/snowdrop/buildpack/docker/ContainerUtils$1.class targeted to JDK 11
[INFO] Ignoring requireUpperBoundDeps in com.google.guava:guava
[WARNING] Rule 2: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceBytecodeVersion failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: com.github.snowdrop:java-buildpack-client:jar:main-9ea258e874-1
Use 'mvn dependency:tree' to locate the source of the banned dependencies.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.539 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-15T20:29:56+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (display-info) on project buildpacks: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException```

How can I fix this error ?
````

Comment: It should be about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850449/how-to-resolve-maven-enforcedbytecodeversion-failure) issue?

Comment: It's almost similar, but it's not exactly the solution, some people can solve the problem this way, but I couldn't solve it, and finally we solved the dependency([java-buildpack-client](https://github.com/snowdrop/java-buildpack-client)) I added by adapting it from Java 11 to Java 8. If you're interested, the project is [here](https://github.com/jromero/buildpacks-jenkins-plugin) now.